# Microsoft Edge Settings Location

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

In `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default`, which files do I need to back up in order to be able to use the settings again during a PC change?

What is the name of the file in which the settings are stored?

Synchronization is not enough. I need to manually transfer / backup the files. With the complete profile it did not work. Only the favorites have been taken over, but not the home page.

Comment: The entire folder.

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I tried, but I'm afraid half of it is missing. Or what folder do you mean?

Comment: You might want to provide that information in your question. Copying your profile should be more than enough. However, you are aware, you can simply synchronize your profile?

Comment: @Ramhound Synchronization is not enough. I need to manually transfer / backup the files.

With the complete profile it did not work.

Only the favorites have been taken over, but not the home page.

Comment: You need to then say that in your question by editing it

Comment: @Ramhound Done.